# Equation for temperature of a given volume if exposed to a given amount of energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

Imagine a certain amount of energy, say 2.092e+14 kilojoules (Roughly the amount of energy reportedly released by the Tsar Bomba) was released into a planck length space. I wanted to say "planck length sphere", but I'm not sure you could call it that.

If timing is an issue, imagine this happens in the time it takes light to travel the planck length.

How would one calculate the temperature that would be experienced at that moment?

The end goal of my question is to satisfy my curiosity about what it might take to achieve a kugleblitz or to reach the planck temperature.

Comment: You would get a black hole if you compressed all that energy into a planck length...

Comment: That's what I'd guess, from the little bit I've read or seen recently, but I wanted to see just how to calculate that. Even if you were to calculate it into a cubic centimeter, I could tweak the inputs as needed to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: I think this QA on Quara is pretty much the same question I asked, but worded differently. I'll see if I can get an understanding of it later.   https://www.quora.com/How-much-energy-is-required-to-create-a-Kugelblitz